# How can I pass values from jsp to servlet using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I want to pass the value of a variable that I retrieve from one servlets to another servlets. I don't want to use session.  For example when I submit the form I want the value of nickname to pass to the second servlet.

## This value  Nickname

```
<li input type="hidden" name="nickname" value="${fn:escapeXml(obj.nickname)}">
  Nickname: <c:out value="${obj.nickname}"/>
</li>
```

I use this link [Stack Example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: your questions isn't very clear, did my answer help solve your problem?

Comment: Servlet A send a value of nickname to a jsp file. I want this value of nickname to past to a Servlet B when i submit the form.

Comment: then yes, you can use a hidden input like in my answer. Give that a try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: JSP SIDE `<li input type="hidden" name="nickname" value="${obj.nickname}" >Nickname:  
                                       <c:out value="${obj.nickname}"/>
                                    </li>`                                                                                                          SERVLET SIDE ` Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
            String nickname = (String)parameterMap.get("nickname")[0];`                         I have NullException

Comment: no not like that, you just need the one line that i wrote in my answer, not in the list. But anywhere in the form. Try like that and let me know.

Comment: check out my edited answer, i explained it some more. Post all your code for the form and ill show you how you can do what you want to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form you can set a hidden input which you pass to your second servlet:

```
<input name="nickname" value="${obj.nickname}" type="hidden"/>
```

This code is wrong, you can't have the word "**input**" randomly as a list attribute.. You also cannot have the **type**, **name** or **value** attribute on a list tag..

```
<li input type="hidden" name="nickname" value="${fn:escapeXml(obj.nickname)}">
  Nickname: <c:out value="${obj.nickname}"/>
</li>
```

Check out the link here below, it shows the legal html tags you can use to send information with a form. You can only use these. So a list won't work.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp